# radix trie with rank/select operations

Tags: algorithm

Now I am implementing a radix trie (also called patricia trie) to index sorted character strings.
So I need a rank() operation to know how many nodes are existed in left of the matched node.
More formally,

```
rankT(x) = |{t∈T | t < x}| for T⊆U and x∈U, where T is a radix trie and U is a universe of key.
meaning that calculation of the number of left leaf nodes in the trie.
```

For example, there are three keys such that

```
key set = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}, and index is 0, 1, 2.
```

So the patricia trie stores these like below:

```
        root
       /  |  \
     abc def ghi
```

and the rank() function should return 1 if key is "def", and 0 if key is "abc".

My question is that how can implement the rank() operation efficiently? I think a recalculation of rank of the node after each insertion is inefficient.

The exposition of radix trie is as below:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to insert words and calculate rank quickly, you could store a value representing the number of words in the subtree on each node. Then when querying the rank you could travel up from the leaf node `x` to the root accumulating the value for the `rank(x)`

So for example you could have a radix trie like (number in paren is number of words in subtree) of words "a", "bcd", "bg" and "def"

```
    root 
   /  |  \
a(1)  |   def(1) 
     b(2)
    /   \ 
  cd(1) g(1)
```

To find the `rank()` of word "bg". You start at node `g(1)` and you go up:

- At node `b(2)` you you accumulate the values of all subtrees left of `g(1)`. Set rank(bg) = size(cd)
- At node `root` you you accumulate the values of all subtrees left of `b(2)`. So
  rank(bg) = size(cd) + size(a) = 1 + 1 = 2

To find the `rank()` of word "def"

- At node `root` you you accumulate the values of all subtrees left of `def(1)`. So
  rank(def) = size(a) + size(b) = 2 + 1 = 3

As far as runtime is concerned: For string `x` you may go through trough `len(x)` parent nodes. And at each node there can be at most `|A|` children, where `A` is your alphabet. So the runtime would be `O(len(x) * |A|)`

Comment: What if I add "be" which has rank 2 after insertion? How can I calculate a rank of the key x while inserting the key?

Comment: As you go down from the root while inserting the node you can calculate its rank the same way as when going up to the root from an already inserted node. However, while inserting you would also have to increment the number stored at each node you pass. You do this because this number represents the words ending in the subtree rooted at that node. That means that while inserting "be" you would have to increment the counter at node "b" from 2 to 3.